# How to get the music player buttons on Android wear like google play music

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have created a notification with normal and expanded view having player controls identical to google play. However, i dont see the notification with play controls on the android wear.

I have tried to build notification with actionButtons rather than remoteViews. Now i am able to see every action as a separate card on wear. But i want the look like the google play on wear. I saw similar screen for VLC player too.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Negative voters, give the solution if it is already there or specify the reason for voting down.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Please I would appreciate your help

Comment: My notification requirement totally changed and then i never looked back. However MediaSession should help out. I will post comments on your question if i find any fix.

Answer (score 1):

Android Wear automatically builds media notifications with play controls when you register a [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) or its Android 5.0 replacement, [MediaSession](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html), using the transport flags you provide to determine which buttons to show and how responses get sent to your app.

Comment: How can I add custom action or page to Wear media notification?

Comment: @konopko - `PlaybackState` has a [getCustomActions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/PlaybackState.html#getCustomActions()) method to retrieve custom actions beyond the usual. No support for additional pages AFAIK.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Can you please elaborate more on your answer? I did create a MediaSession Notification. But on the android wear, each action is shown on page. How can I have them on the same page? Thanks!

Comment: @ZiadHalabi - how did you build your notification? You should be using a [MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) notification and attaching your active `MediaSession` via [setMediaSession()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html#setMediaSession(android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.Token)).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you for your reply. If you can please post a detailed answer to my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988523/android-wear-notification-with-mediasession . This way I can give you credit for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create custom notification like I described here
   [Android Wear : Custom Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014866/android-wear-custom-notifications/27107229#27107229)
2. but best solution I think is to create full screen application for wear.
   you can check google sdk sample or github how to do it
   https://github.com/mauimauer/AndroidWearable-Samples/tree/master/SkeletonWearableApp

and send message to wear from phone when you need to open it.
Good way to open wear activity from android phone you can find in DataLayer sample app.