# Android Wear Notification with MediaSession

Tags: java, android, notifications, wear-os

I would like to make an android wear notification using MediaSession that has several buttons on one page and some other buttons on a different page. It would look like Google Play Now App notification on an android wear. I followed this github tutorial at https://github.com/PaulTR/AndroidDemoProjects/blob/master/MediaSessionwithMediaStyleNotification/app/src/main/java/com/ptrprograms/mediasessionwithmediastylenotification/MediaPlayerService.java

However, each action was added to a separate page on the android wear. I want to group some of them into one page. For instance, the play/pause, pre and next on one page and the rate button on a second page. I would like to know if it is possible to achieve that with a custom notification without using MediaSession in order to cover API less than 21.

Thanks!

```
private void buildNotification( Notification.Action action ) {
            Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();

            Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class );
            intent.setAction( ACTION_STOP );
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder( this )
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle( "Media Title" )
                    .setContentText( "Media Artist" )
                    .setDeleteIntent( pendingIntent )
                    .setStyle(style);

            builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", ACTION_PREVIOUS ) );
            builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_rew, "Rewind", ACTION_REWIND ) );
            builder.addAction( action );
            builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_ff, "Fast Foward", ACTION_FAST_FORWARD ) );
            builder.addAction( generateAction( android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", ACTION_NEXT ) );
            style.setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2,3,4);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
            notificationManager.notify( 1, builder.build() );
    }
```

UPDATED CODE: The the setMediaSession is giving this compiling error when I pass it a token: The method setMediaSession(MediaSessionCompat.Token) in the type NotificationCompat.MediaStyle is not applicable for the arguments (MediaSession.Token). The 3 actions are still being displayed on 3 separate pages on the android wear.

```
private void buildNotification( Notification.Action action ) {
    NotificationCompat.MediaStyle style = new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle();
    //style.setMediaSession(mSession.getSessionToken());            
    style.setMediaSession(null);            
    style.setShowActionsInCompactView(1,2);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pinkfloyd);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this );
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setLargeIcon(icon);
    builder.setContentTitle( "Media Title" );
    builder.setContentText( "Media Artist" );
    builder.setColor(Color.argb(0, 60, 13, 77));
    builder.setStyle(style);

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Test1 ", null);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Test2 ", null);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Test3 ", null);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificationManager.notify( 1, builder.build() );
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) in place of [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html)? Same API, but backward compatible as well.

Answer (score 4):

One feature added in AppCompat v22.2.0 is [NotificationCompat.MediaStyle](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/JmfwJeVGRxQ) - this gives you a backward compatible way to build media notifications and pass media information to Android 5.0+ devices, working alongside [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) to provide information to Android Wear on older devices (as well as adding lockscreen controls on API14-19 devices).

When you build a [MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) notification, it is critical to call [setMediaSession()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html#setMediaSession(android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.Token)) which tells Android Wear that your notification is attached to media playback, giving you the 4 action on a single card style notification.

Comment: Please check my updated question. I tried what you suggested and yet the 3 actions are shown on 3 different pages on the android wear.

Comment: Android Wear pulls the play/pause/previous/next buttons from your [PlaybackStateCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.html) you've set onto your `MediaSessionCompat`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Can you help me how to hide the wear notification. I don't want Android wear to pull the play states from `MediaSessionCompat` . I have a custom notification triggered from the wear app. I don't use `MediaStyle` notification